# In vim ex mode, what does @% do?

Tags: vim, ex

I was writing a little vim leader mapping to convert a file in (GitHub flavoured markdown) to a pdf.

Both of these work, and seem to be functionally equivalent:

```
nnoremap <expr> <leader>pdf ':! pandoc -f markdown_github --latex-engine=xelatex ' . shellescape(@%,1). ' -o ' . shellescape(expand('%:r'), 1) . ".pdf \<cr>"

nnoremap <expr> <leader>pdf ':! pandoc -f markdown_github --latex-engine=xelatex ' . shellescape(expand('%'),1). ' -o ' . shellescape(expand('%:r'), 1) . ".pdf \<cr>"
```

I had the first one working (thanks Stack Overflow ;) but I didn't really understand the `@%` in the first shellescape. So I replaced it with the `expand('%')` which I "get" a bit more.

Can anyone explain the difference, or even where to go to look this up? I did read `:help :@` but it talks about `Execute the contents of register as an ex command`, which, doesn't *seem* to be what is happening here.

Any help / pointers would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@%` is a register that contains the name of the file associated with the current buffer. It can be used like any other register, for example:

```
i<C-r>%
"%p
```

In your first example, `shellescape()` expects a String as its first parameter and outputs a String. It happens so that the type of `@%` is String so `@%` can be used directly.

Comment: Thanks for that. It was the `execute` part that confused me.  Executing the name of my file as an ex command would have (I'd thought) have broken things. Is it actually "executing" the register, or is the `%` register a special one in that when it is "executed" it just returns itself?

Comment: The `@<register>` notation is used for two things: a) execute the content of `<register>` as if it was an Ex command (in cmd-line mode) or a macro (in normal mode) and b) use the content of `<register>` in an expression. But I must admit Vimscript is full of ambiguities like this. If in doubt, read the relevant section of the doc.